# Laravel + Beanstalkd queue - buried jobs getting kicked

Tags: laravel, queue, beanstalkd

I'm using Laravel 4.1 with beanstalkd to run some intensive Photoshop PSD file processing in the background. I also installed [phpBeanstalkdAdmin](http://mnapoli.fr/phpBeanstalkdAdmin/) to monitor what's going on the queue.

The jobs being processed take around 7-10 minutes, but I've noticed that some of my jobs get restarted, even when they are still busy running.

Keeping an eye on phpBeanstalkdAdmin, I can see the job being **buried** when queue:listen picks up the job, but after a while it gets kicked back up, to **ready**.

To start the listening to the queue, I'm using:

```
$ ./artisan queue:listen --queue=my_queue --memory=512 --timeout=600
```

Inside the queue handler's fire() method, I'm simply starting an artisan command with

```
    Artisan::call(
        'tms:parse',
        [
            '--alias' => $data['alias'],
            '--notify' => $data['email']
        ]
    );
```

and calling

```
if ($job != null) {
    $job->delete();
}
```

once the job is done. But I can't figure out why it gets kicked to ready halfway through the job being busy.

Does Laravel kick the job back to ready after nothing happens to it in a preconfigured interval?

Comment: There is a way better tool than phpBeanstalkdAdmin, it's Beanstalkd Console: https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this issue was resolved a while back, no one bothered updating the Laravel documentation however:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3766